# Interdependancy of C++ libraries with CMake

Tags: c++, compilation, linker, cmake

What and how to do with CMake files in such a away one would not have to take care of the dependency order? (see my previous question related the issue [Strange error: undefined reference to `class::class()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538967/strange-error-undefined-reference-to-classclass)).

For instance if you have lib A dependent of lib B, which by its turn is dependent of lib C one would code

```
add_library({MY_LIB} A B C)
```

How to do to not be forced to follow the order? In the near past I just did

```
target_link_libraries({MY_LIB} {MY_LIB})
```

But this is no longer working for me.... I do not know why (???). This problem is quite irritating since I have a large number of interdependent libraries...

Any suggestion please (am using cmake 3.5.2, gcc version 4.8.4 on Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)?

Comment: Could you include the CMakeLists.txt for which `target_link_libraries({MY_LIB} {MY_LIB})` is failing?

Answer (score 2):

An `add_library` command to create each library, and then set the dependencies with `target_link_libraries` should be enough.

In your case you would have e.g.

```
add_library(A ${sources_for_A})
add_library(B ${sources_for_B})
add_library(C ${sources_for_C})

target_link_libraries(A B)  # A depends on B
target_link_libraries(B C)  # B depends on C

# Executable using the libraries
add_executable(program ${sources_for_program})
target_link_libraries(program A)  # Program uses library A (and B and C indirectly)
```

It should not matter if the libraries are `STATIC` or `SHARED`.

Comment: target_link_library or target_link_libraries? What is the difference please?

Comment: Am getting this error message `Unknown CMake command "target_link_library"`

Comment: @polar [`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/target_link_libraries.html). And you need to tell CMake the dependencies you have, otherwise it could build library B before library C, and for a shared library that won't work. If you only have static libraries, and the order doesn't matter (and there's no auto-generated files that parts of your project depends on) then you can skip the order, and add all libraries for the `program` target.

Comment: But I was able in the near past to link the libraries regardless of their order, by just duplicating the the libraries; e.g. `target_ling_libraries(program {MY_LIB} {MY_LIB}.... {MY_LIB})`. I do not understand why I would need to take care of the order ONLY NOW... Very strange

Comment: @polar What a surprise, you got [again the same answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37541138/2436175). :P